# setting flash messages on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, drupal-7, migration, flash-message

I'm migrating from drupal to wordpress and I'm new on coding wordpress. I need a function that works similar to drupal_set_message() to display a message on on a failed custom login(not site/wp-admin) but i can't find any.

Comment: I've just answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23898327/2752041), maybe it could be of help.